# how to skip a day to previous in sql database if that day produce no files

Tags: sql-server, date

i need to print the files From the current day plus from the day before...but if the day before is sunday then i want to print the files from saturday

i have a database containing a files of a month..each day produces some files but sunday is a holiday and at that day no files are generated.now i have done the  query to pick the files in such a way that giving current date will results the files of that day and previous day. But the problem is on monday when i give the current date it produces files of monday and sunday... i dont want to print files of sunday as it is null,instead of that when am giving the current date if its is monday i should get the files of saturday instead of monday.
this is the code am using now

```
select files from table1 where [date]>=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-1),0) ";
```

except for sundays i have entered the files for each day

```
 insert into dbtable(date,files) values('date value',' filename');
```

Comment: Why you have tagged `MySQL` ? I think you are using SQL Server.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Which records do you actually want to select? From the current day? From the last day before current? From the current day plus from the day before? From the two days before the current day? Or still something different?

Comment: From the current day plus from the day before...but if the day before is sunday then i want to print the files from saturday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MySQL function `DAYNAME(date1)` to check for day is `sunday`,If so then get difference of two days instead of one.

```
mysql> SELECT DAYNAME(GETDATE());
+-----------------------+
| DAYNAME('2008-05-15') |
+-----------------------+
| Thursday              | 
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you are using SQL server,you can try `datename` function to get the day name:

```
datename(dw,getdate())
```

Try this for SQL Server:

```
SELECT files from table1 
where [date]>=DATEADD(DAY,case when datename(dw,(GETDATE()-1))='SUNDAY' THEN -2 ELSE -1 END,getdate());
```

For MySQL Server Try:

```
SELECT files from table1 
where `date`>=DATE_SUB(current_Date,interval (case when DAYNAME(date_sub(current_date,interval 1 day))='SUNDAY' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) day);
```

Comment: i need to print the files From the current day plus from the day before...but if the day before is sunday then i want to print the files from saturday

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[date]>=DATEADD(DAY,case when datename(dw,(GETDATE()-1))='SUNDAY' THEN -1 ELSE -' at line 2

Comment: i got an error when i give this query am using mysql server

Comment: This query works on SQL -Server database. and also you have tagged SQL server in your question.

Comment: You have tagged SQL server and Query syntax  in question is also of SQL Server. I am updating the answer for MySQL also. Please  Tag MySQL in question to get correct answers.

Comment: am sorry am using microsoft sql server

Comment: Yes this query works in microsoft sql server but the error you have written in comment is of MySQL not SQL server.

Comment: SQL server and MySQL are two different database system.

Comment: still am getting -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[date]>=DATEADD(DAY,case when datename(dw,(GETDATE()-1))='SUNDAY' THEN -1 ELSE -' at line 1

Comment: am sorry i got confused at first am using ms sql server 2005

Comment: I think you are using MySQL not MS SQL-Server because this error is from MySQL.

Comment: @halfe: I have updated the answer for MySQL . Check once

Answer (score 1):

Look for *both* dates, the current and the one before. From these records take the newer one.

```
select files
from table1 
where date =
( 
  select max(date) 
  from table1
  where date in (getdate(), getdate() - interval 1 day)
);
```

(Updated regarding Code-Monk's commment. Thanks.)

This is standard SQL except for the date manipulation which is MySQL specific. If you were mistaken with the DBMS tagged, then replace the part where a day is subtracted from current day with what's appropriate for your DBMS.)

**UPDATE:** You want to select from two days, the currect day and the last date before. As there should be no future records, this always means the two maximum dates in your table.

The slightly altered query using ORDER BY and LIMIT:

```
select files
from table1 
where date in
( 
  select date
  from table1
  order by date desc limit 2
);
```

Comment: But this will not return more than 1 record if multiple records exist for that day

Comment: Code-Monk: Ah, I didn't see there can be more records for a day. Thanks for pointing this out. Then one would get the date in a subquery and get the files in the outer query. About the same logic, only one step more to go. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are using SQL Server (and not MySQL), you can use a CROSS APPLY to get data for the last two [dates] with files:

```
SELECT  *
FROM   dbo.table1 o
       CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 2 [date]
                     FROM     dbo.table1 i
                     GROUP BY [date]
                     WHERE [date]>=DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-5),0)
                     ORDER BY  [date] DESC
            ) det
WHERE det.[date] = o.[date]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works, because I don't have mysql here to test (only SQL Server):

```
SELECT files FROM table1
WHERE CAST([date] AS DATE) IN (CURDATE() - CASE DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) WHEN 2 /* Monday */ THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, CURDATE())
```

The idea is to test if the date (as date only, no time part) falls in a specific list of dates, being today and yesterday or Saturday.